# multiple dims lastrow vba

Tags: excel, vba

Im not too familiar with VBA, so the code below is mostly just copy and paste and research, just cant couldnt find a way to use Dim multiple times to be able to use it for different columns. Is there something I could add in front of "lastrow" to make it a different without getting the "compile error: Duplication declaration in current scope".

```
   Dim lastrow As Long
        lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim pointer As Integer
        pointer = 1
   Do Until pointer > lastrow - 1
        Range("D1").Select
        Sheet1.Range("D" & pointer).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        pointer = pointer + 1
   Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the line with `.Select` in it, as it is not needed, and you can set the `.NumberFormat` of multiple cells within the loop if you want.

But there is an easier way, you can set the `.NumberFormat` property of an entire column with one line of code and no loop:

```
WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

And for that matter, you can do multiple columns all at once too...

```
WorkSheets("Sheet1").Range("D:E,G:G,I:J").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Comment: I have 2 cells, ex: on F and G that needs to have their lastrow not lastrow -1 changed. mm/dd/yyyy (Lastrow for Column F) and hh:mm:ss (lastrow for column G).

Comment: ok, so do that in your loop then. You can re-use the same variable. No need to declare it twice.

Comment: So I realised when I used the same variable, forgot to change the name on heet1.Range("D" & pointer**1**).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: Also, realised that I had my loop in a loop.. took the pointer out of the For loop I had and that worked..... It took someone 2 seconds to see my mistake.. still learning vba

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* dim a variable multiple times in one function or sub (hence the syntax error). There are some programming languages such as Java which has a notion of block-level scope in which such redeclarations are possible. VBA is not one of those languages.

Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835) and what you really want to do is to *reinitialize* the variable in each pass through an outer loop. That is nonproblematic, just `lastrow = 0` whenever you are tempted to redeclare it.

That said, for this particular problem follow the recommendations of braX. In VBA, it is often possible to deal with ranges as a whole rather than looping cell by cell.

Comment: Realised that I had my loop in a loop.. took the pointer out of the For loop I had and that worked..... It took someone 2 seconds to see my mistake.. still learning vba